# Clickable zone expands to container (image)

Tags: css

I've set images in links, and it works, except that the clickable zone expands to the whole container (parent of the image.) (the orange part in the image below)

[**Screenshot** of the clickable zone](http://aurelieremia.be/screenshot.jpg)

Here's the part of the code concerning this problem (I'm not putting all in it, all the images  have the same problem.) :

**HTML:**

```
<a href="img/tableau/tableau-01.jpg">
    <img src="img/tableau/tableau-01.jpg" alt="tableau 01"/>
</a>

<a href="img/tableau/tableau-02.jpg">
     <img src="img/tableau/tableau-02.jpg" alt="tableau 02"/>
</a>

<a href="img/tableau/tableau-02.jpg">
    <img src="img/tableau/tableau-03.jpg" alt="tableau 03"/>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 900px;
}

img {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 0.13s;
       -moz-transition: all ease-in 0.13s;
         -o-transition: all ease-in 0.13s;
        -ms-transition: all ease-in 0.13s;
            transition: all ease-in 0.13s;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

And there's the [link of the site](http://aurelieremia.be/tia1/mes-grilles-mes-premiers-pas/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

why did you set display to block? if you remove this and let the default which i think is inline-block it fixes it. if you want to center it you can use other methods.

Comment: Yes, but it seemed like to best method to center an image to me. I don't need to know the width of the image to set a negative margin with this method.

Comment: @Naemy not sure but i think there is a problem when you set a block element inside a <a> tag and then set margin auto. it then occupies all the space of the parent element (because <a> tag is inline element and have no boundaries so it take the place of the first parent element which is block element and has boundaries). if i remember well the most bulletproof method is with javascript. If the dimension of the image is x then you just put left=(container width) - x/2.